# file not binding to angularjs service using FormData

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services, angular-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using angularjs and spring 3, I have written a service which is not binding the selected file. I don't know what mistake I have been doing, please help me to solve this problem. I am using commonsmultipart for uploading the files. following are the fileUploadService and controller codes.

```
MyApp.service('fileUploadService', function ($http, $q) {        
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl, formData) {
        //FormData, object of key/value pair for form fields and values
        var fileFormData = new FormData();
        fileFormData.append('fileUpload', file);
      //  console.log(formData);
        fileFormData.append('name', formData.name);
        fileFormData.append('email', formData.email);
        fileFormData.append('password', formData.password);
        fileFormData.append('mobile_no', formData.mobile_no);
        fileFormData.append('register-submit', 'Register Now');

        var deffered = $q.defer();
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fileFormData, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

        }).success(function (response) {
            deffered.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (response) {
            deffered.reject(response);
        });

        return deffered.promise;
    }
});
```

*Spring Controller:*

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "static-access" })
    @RequestMapping( value="/RegisterCandidate" ,  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private String RegisterCandidate(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload ) throws Exception{

        System.out.println("In method");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        System.out.println("email==============="+email);
        String Password = request.getParameter("password");
        String usr_name = request.getParameter("name");
        String mobile_no = request.getParameter("mobile_no");
        Date dateentry = new Date();
        java.sql.Timestamp entry_date = new Timestamp(dateentry.getTime()); 
        Users_Pojo usr  = new Users_Pojo(); 

        if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
            for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload){                             
                usr.setFilename(aFile.getOriginalFilename());
                usr.setFile_data(aFile.getBytes());


                System.out.println("aFile.getBytes()======"+aFile.getBytes());
                System.out.println("aFile.getInputStream()======"+aFile.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("aFile.getStorageDescription()======"+aFile.getStorageDescription());
                System.out.println("aFile.getSize();======"+aFile.getSize());
                System.out.println("aFile.getContentType();==="+aFile.getContentType());/*  */


            }
        }
        MD5CodeGenerator md5 = new MD5CodeGenerator();

        usr.setUc_password(md5.convertToMD5(Password));
        usr.setUc_name(email);
        usr.setUc_contact_person(email);
        usr.setUc_phone_no(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.parseLong(mobile_no)));
        usr.setUc_email_id(email);
        usr.setUc_type_id(1);
        usr.setUc_active(1);
        usr.setValid_from(null);
        usr.setValid_to(null);
        usr.setDesignation("jobseekar");
        usr.setIp_address("164.100.19.79");
        usr.setUser_location(1);
        usr.setEntry_date(entry_date);

        scm_service.save(usr, email);

        return "success";

    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this service function ?  What i would suggest is that on change of the file upload append the file to data as you will have file reference in that event. And then swnd the formdata to this function for upload

Comment: Dear @Manish, please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970697/angularjs-fileupload-with-promise-not-working-in-spring-mvc  I have described it in detail

Comment: I didnt get one thing you said file data is not posting to controller what do youu mean by that?

Comment: @Manish, I am using commonsmultipart, when I print the file data, I am getting like this: 
 aFile.getBytes()======[B@103d405d
aFile.getInputStream()======java.io.FileInputStream@254ca1ff
aFile.getStorageDescription()======at [E:\E Drive\Bharath\Personal\Spring SCM WorksSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\Mechasoft\upload_2caf46df_161f0121603__8000_00000000.tmp]
aFile.getSize();======40653
aFile.getContentType();===application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: what i can infer from all this is that you want to display the file on the UI as well as upload it to the server. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: No @Manish, I am simply uploading a word/pdf file directly, I mean I am not showing it on UI, When I check the console after uploading the file I am able to see name, email, password, mobile_no expect file on browser, I am getting status code 200, but when I download the same file ms-word showing the file is currupted error.

Comment: You wont be able to see the file contents in the console. I think you need check if your file is being saved correctly on the server side and retrieved properly. May a server side problem.

Comment: @Manish, I have updated my question can you please check it.

Comment: I would have loved to do but m not a baceknd guy :P. M not the right person to check that.

Comment: @Manish, did you find any wrong with my frontend code? I have been thinking that the problem is in frontend, if you say I'll concentrate backend, thank you.

Comment: It seems fine to me. Thats why i suggested to check your backend.

Comment: @Manish, I have done it using only spring, now I am trying to do it with angularjs, should I use enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form with angularjs?

Comment: have you ensured file content has been really sent? there are different cross-browser [compatibility issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility) with FormData. So it's better to ensure you have not faced one of them.

Comment: @skyboyer, we can't see the file contents in the browser console, but when I print using  .getByte() method in spring controller it showing like "[B@6b02547c"